# How to get a psychology research assistant position?

Tags: social-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, statistics, social-cognition

I am a recent postgraduate student of social psychology and I have been trying to look for RA positions without much luck. My applications are getting rejected without any feedback and I am a little lost as to what I am doing wrong. I was wondering if anybody would have any advice on how to secure an RA position. I am also applying through jobs.ac.uk, indeed and LinkedIn, apart from these websites, are there any other resources to apply through? Also, would anyone know if any paid RA positions are available in any of the universities?

Any advice would be really appreciated!

Comment: You might have better luck posting this on workplace.SE instead.  I believe that many institutions post positions on their own web sites - [here](https://www.torontomu.ca/psychology/research-and-innovation/research-opportunities/) is the page at mine.  These positions are often very competitive - personally (just my opinion) I would take that as a market signal to consider a different industry.  Good luck!

Comment: In some places, "research assistant" is a graduate student (PhD) position specifically. If you're applying to those jobs without realizing that it might explain the futility.